# Configuring react-router-dom generates an error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Im trying to set up a new react app.

I'm having trouble configuring the router (i think).

So far, my index.js has:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import About from './pages/about/About';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />

        </Switch>
      </div>  
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I also have a footer in my / path that has a link with:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Typography } from 'antd';


const { Text, Title } = Typography;

function StandardFooter() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row type="flex" justify="space-around">
            <Col span={4}>
                <Text type="secondary">
                    <Link to={'/about'} >About</Link>
                </Text> <br />

            </Col>
            <Col span={4}>
                <Text strong>Legal</Text>
            </Col>

        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default StandardFooter;
```

But when I try to render this I get an error that says: Error: Invariant failed: You should not use Link outside a Router

I have tried removing and reinstalling react-router-dom. It doesn't make any difference.  Is there a step missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line: `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

This line is likely the source of the error, since your `<App />` component tree contains a `<Link />`, and you're rendering it without `<BrowserRouter />` in this instance.

Comment: Im such a donkey some times. i forgot to delete the starter code. thanks. i have to wait 6 minutes to accept